# How do i solve the following state machine using signals and posix

Tags: unix, signals, posix

The system has four processess, P!,P2,P3, and P4. P2 and p# will execute the following taks upon completion of one after the other. P4 will verify and acknowlefe the completion of p2 and p3 and assign taks(in the order listed below) as per the below list. (the list is just a taks of exec that I execulate using which i dont know I tried execl which did not work properly, it only exec only one program others did not exec) P1 will provide the input required and a tak start commond for the taks assigned by p4 to p3 and p2. All taks have to be continuosly computed repeated till it recieves a termination signal.I tired execl for executing the programs inside multiple forkes, and for one the programs I needed to insert arguments which I dont know How ot do. I have to do this all in C, Pooisx commands. I am kinda of a noob in signalling that is also hard. Do help.

Comment: Verbal descriptions of problems are often hard to understand and or ambiguous. Please update your question with the smallest amount of your current code that demonstrates the problem, including small sample input of what should be processes, vs what should be skipped, the required output from that same input, your current output and exact text of error messages. I recommend you figure this out in pseudo-code first or a higher level language. Read [mcve] about expectations for questions here. Good luck.